# Не получается вызвать статический метод класса в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Класс topic, с вызовом метода из которого у меня возникают проблемы:

```
#.tools  - where definded get_current_time, generate_id
#db is object of class and have method excute_query, wich send query to
from .tools import *

class topic:
    
    def __init__(self,theme,author,about,db):
        self.time_of_creation = get_current_time
        self.theme = theme
        self.author = author
        self.about = about
        self.sb_id = generate_id()
        self.db = db

        try:
            #inserting data into DB
            self.db.excute_query(f"""INSERT INTO user VALUES ("{get_current_time()}, '{self.theme}', 
                                                            '{self.author}','{self.about}',
                                                            '{generate_id()}')""")
            
            return 1
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return [0, str(e)]
        
    @staticmethod
    def all(self):
        return self.db.excute_query("SELECT * FROM topic")
```

Я пытаюсь вызвать метод all():

```
topic.all()
```

и в ответ получаю AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'all'. Как мне это исправить?

Comment: self нет в статических методах

Comment: 1) Первое правило при использовании  конструктора - конструктор `__init__` не должен ничего возвращать. 2) Класс по соглашению нужно писать с большой буквы. 3) Верно подметили в комментарии - статический метод не содержит ссылки на класс, либо где-то переиспользуете название переменных/функций

Comment: Переименуйте класс. Ошибка уйдёт? Есть подозрение, что у вас конфликт имён.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, в данном случае может подойти метод класса ([`@classmethod`](https://pythonist.ru/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-vs-prostye-metody/)):

```
class Topic:
    db = None

    def __init__(self, db):
        Topic.db = db

    @classmethod
    def select_all(cls):
        if cls.db:
            return f'Все данные из: {cls.db}'
        else:
            return 'Вы не указали БД'


print(Topic.select_all())
print(Topic('БазаДанных').select_all())
```

```
Вы не указали БД
Все данные из: БазаДанных
```

Comment: Только с этим надо будет работать как с синглтоном...

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант — вместо статического метода используйте самостоятельную функцию. Для того

1. Удалите строку

   ```
       @staticmethod
   ```
2. Вместо параметра `self` (который вам нужен только для определения, с которой датабазой вы хотите работать), примените прямо параметр `db`

   ```
       def all_(db):
   ```

   Обратите внимание на то, что вместо имени `all` я применил имя `all_`, т.к. `all` является именем стандартной функции Питона.
3. Удалите отступ перед этим определением функции — вам не нужно, чтобы она была связана с вашим классом `topic`, и соответственно уменьшите отступ следующей команды. Ну и в этой команде удалите часть `self.` и вместо `topic` примените имя вашей таблицы — из вашего кода я гадаю, что оно `user`:

   ```
   def all_(db):
       return db.excute_query("SELECT * FROM user")
   ```

Затем вы можете вызывать эту функцию в виде `all_(имя_датабазы)`.

---

Второй вариант — исправите ваш статический метод. Для того отбросите `self`, т.к. статический метод не знает ничего ни об объекте, ни о классе. Значит,

вместо

```
    @staticmethod
    def all(self):
        return self.db.excute_query("SELECT * FROM topic")
```

используйте

```
    @staticmethod
    def all_(db):
        return db.excute_query("SELECT * FROM user")
```

Затем вы можете вызывать этот метод в виде `topic.all_(имя_датабазы)`.